# Sharepoint Online - Item only add permission. Not view permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I must create a permission, at Sharepoint Online with only Add element permission, not add and view permission to element. I could create only add permission on Farm server, but I haven't create this permision on Sharepoint Online. How could I do it ? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint gives the possibility to customize the permissions on list level. it's possible to set permissions (roles) to single users or groups. There is also the possibility the create a new role with custom defined permissions.

Go to the Home WebsiteSettings (http://portal/_layouts/15/settings.aspx) -> Website Permissions (http://portal/_layouts/15/user.aspx)-> Permission Levels (http://portal/_layouts/15/role.aspx) -> Add Role.

By adding a new Role you can specify what a role is permitted to do. In your case add only the `Add Elements`.

[Office Support Page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-create-and-edit-Permission-Levels-53c86040-07fa-4ea7-bc55-34ee96b437fe)

Comment: Thanks But I don't understand. What should I Find. Could You take a screen shots ?

Comment: I don't see any role permissions. How could I find this ?

Comment: oh....I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I was talking about abount SharePoint Server. I'm not familiar with the online version.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late reply to this! But the best way to make an upload library is to use Document Approval in Versioning settings. Then set the Only Approvers can see minor versions.

Comment: But now how to find out what is Used or not in My Site Pages ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @GrzegorzZ

Answer (score -1):

At site collection site settings, Site permissions > Permission levels > Add a permission level

Comment: But there if I adding a Add Permission to the item it automating adding me Read Item. But I want adding, withoud read Permissions

Comment: Read and view permissions are not the same thing.

Comment: But I can't check Add element, without read element.